# Python numpy reshape 3d list into 2d array

Tags: python, numpy, reshape, flatten

I wish to convert

edit : the code below is a 3D list of list,

```
[
    [ 
        [
            [1,2,3,],
            [4,5,6,],
        ],
        [
            [7,8,9,],
            [10,11,12,], 
        ],
    ],
    [ 
        [
            [A,B,C,],
            [D,E,F,], 
        ],
        [
            [G,H,I,],
            [J,K,L,], 
        ],
    ],
]
```

Into

```
[

[1,2,3],
[4,5,6],
[7,8,9],
[10,11,12],
[A,B,C],
[D,E,F],
[G,H,I],
[J,K,L]

]
```

I have tried numpy.flatten but with no success
    https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.flatten.html

Comment: Have you tried `my_array.reshape(8, 3)`?

Comment: Since you have characters and numbers in your list, I recommend using pandas instead of numpy

Comment: What `dtype` do you want?  What are `A`, `B` etc.  As shown those are variables, not strings.  As such they must have values, which in Python could be anything.  Variable ids won't display in the actual list (or array).

Answer (score 2):

Reshape is your tool.

Here is a self contained example:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([
    [[[1,2,3] , [4,5,6]],
     [[7,8,9] , [10,11,12]]],
    [[[13,14,15] , [16,17,18]],
     [[19,20,21] , [22,23,24]]]
    ])

a.shape
>>> (2, 2, 2, 3)

a.reshape(8,3)
>>> array([[ 1,  2,  3],
>>>        [ 4,  5,  6],
>>>        [ 7,  8,  9],
>>>        [10, 11, 12],
>>>        [13, 14, 15],
>>>        [16, 17, 18],
>>>        [19, 20, 21],
>>>        [22, 23, 24]])
```

Comment: or `a.reshape(-1,3)` if you don't want to pre-calculate the number of rows.

Comment: Thanks Jurgen and @Dan . but I found that my code is a 3D list of lists, not a 3D array. I edited my question : how to convert 3D lit of list into a 2D array.

Comment: @BrigitteCharpent you can use `np.array()` and `list` to convert between the two and still use this method

Comment: Thanks to all of you. I had difficulties transforming eachlist level into an array level. Finally I simply iterated over my lists in plain simple Python.